# sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_WRAPPED_KEY_INVALID

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle, pkcs#11

I want to decrypt a `CMSEnvelopedData`using `BouncyCastle`and `PKCS11`libraries in java.
Everything was going well until I encountered this problem:

I can successfully retrieve recipient information:

> ```
> CMSEnvelopedData cmsEnvelopedData = new CMSEnvelopedData(signedAndEncryptedMessage);
>
>         Collection recip = cmsEnvelopedData.getRecipientInfos().getRecipients();
>         KeyTransRecipientInformation rinfo = (KeyTransRecipientInformation)recip.iterator().next();
> ```

Now, when I want to decrypt this data using recipient private key:

```
if (rinfo != null) {
            LOGGER.debug("Decrypting...");

            byte[] receivedData = rinfo.getContent(
                    new JceKeyTransEnvelopedRecipient(
                            recipientPrivateKey
                            // PKCS11
                    ).setProvider(SUN_PKCS11_PROVIDER).setContentProvider(BOUNCY_CASTLE_PROVIDER).setContentProvider(SUN_PKCS11_PROVIDER)
                    // MSCAPI
//                   ).setProvider(SUN_MSCAPI_PROVIDER)
            );
            LOGGER.debug("Done decrypting...");
```

I've got this exception:

```
org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSException: exception unwrapping key: bad padding: doFinal() failed
    at org.bouncycastle.cms.jcajce.JceKeyTransRecipient.extractSecretKey(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.cms.jcajce.JceKeyTransEnvelopedRecipient.getRecipientOperator(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.cms.KeyTransRecipientInformation.getRecipientOperator(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.cms.RecipientInformation.getContentStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.cms.RecipientInformation.getContent(Unknown Source)
    at ir.dpi.pki.namad.cms.Main.decryptAndVerify(Main.java:283)
    at ir.dpi.pki.namad.cms.Main.main(Main.java:92)
    at ir.dpi.pki.namad.cms.MainTest.mainTest_DecryptAndVerify(MainTest.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: org.bouncycastle.operator.OperatorException: bad padding: doFinal() failed
    at org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JceAsymmetricKeyUnwrapper.generateUnwrappedKey(Unknown Source)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: doFinal() failed
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11RSACipher.implDoFinal(P11RSACipher.java:362)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11RSACipher.engineDoFinal(P11RSACipher.java:387)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_WRAPPED_KEY_INVALID
    at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.C_Decrypt(Native Method)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11RSACipher.implDoFinal(P11RSACipher.java:341)
    ... 37 more
```

I can not figure out the problem. I am using a Nexus smart card reader (smart token) which consists of my private key and a valid certificate.

Comment: Possible cases for `BadPaddingException` are partial (or truncated) input data or mismatched cipher mode/padding. Can you somehow check that the cms message is read fully and that the cipher/mode/padding using to decode the wrapped secret key is correct?

Comment: How can I check that? I mean all I know after debugging is that CMS message is not empty and I can retrieve recipient information from it successfully. Isn't that mean it is readable? And about cipher/mode/padding which is used, I have no idea how I can check the method for correctness! Would you please give me a hint?

Comment: Trivial way to check whether you use cipher correctly is to encrypt some hard-coded data, then decrypt it back and compare with original contents. Also, BouncyCastle is open-sourced, you can locate precisely which line of code throws the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, I hope this post will help those who may encounter this kind of exception.
In my code I encrypted the message with a `RecipientCertificate` which is not the same as my Decryption Certificate in Recipient's Smart Token! I made this mistake and it takes me the whole three days to resolve it. Anyway, `BadPaddingException` made me think about cipher mode or padding.